# classpath not working on javac command

Tags: java

I want to specify the classpath on the javac command. But when I use the ";" to separate the paths of the classpath, I get the error "path not found".

How to code the javac command to have two folders in the classpath?

```
-- this works
PS C:\vsctest\myTask> javac -classpath c:\packages *.java

-- this does not work. why?
PS C:\vsctest\myTask> javac -classpath .;c:\packages *.java
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
c:\packages : The term 'c:\packages' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:20
+ javac -classpath .;c:\packages *.java
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:\packages:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to put it in quotes anyway: `javac -classpath ".;c:\packages" *.java`

Comment: This is specific to PowerShell - I suspect it's handling `.;c:\packages` in a special way. Try the same thing from a regular command shell

Comment: yes. the quotes worked.  thanks.
javac -classpath ".;c:\packages" *.java